# Оптимизация функции numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Ниже приведена реализация функции по заполнению аккумуляторного массива (пространства Хафа). Возможно ли её подвергнуть ещё большей оптимизации? Больше всего времени эта функция проводит вот в этой строчке:

```
accum += index * np.apply_along_axis(np.bincount, axis=0, arr=ro_calc, minlength=accum.shape[0])
```

Необходим оптимальный по времени переход от текущего шага:

```
>>>ro_calc = (point @ sin_cos + img_diagonal).astype(np.int32)
>>>ro_calc
        array([[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5],
               [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],
               [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
               [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
               [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

к

```
>>>accum += index * np.apply_along_axis(np.bincount, axis=0, arr=ro_calc, minlength=accum.shape[0])
>>>accum
        array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
               [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
               [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
               [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1.],
               [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 2., 2., 2.],
               [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 2.]])
```

Ниже представлена полная реализация текущей функции.

```
def hough_transform(processed_image, mark, accum, sin_cos, img_diagonal, index=1) -> None:
    """

    :param processed_image: входное маркированное изображение (каждой области соответствует целое число)
    :param mark: метка, соответствующая исследуемой области
    :param accum: аккумуляторный массив Хафа, пространство Хафа
    :param sin_cos: вычисленные значения sin и cos
    :param img_diagonal: длина диагонали прямоугольника, ограничивающего исследуемую область
    :param index: 1 - для увеличения значения в аккумуляторном массиве, -1 - для уменьшения
    :return: None, изменение массива происходит на месте

    >>>point = np.array([[1, 2],[1, 3],[2, 2],[2, 3],[3, 3]])
    >>>sin_cos = [[-1.0, -0.9986, -0.9945, -0.9877, -0.9781, -0.9659, -0.9511, -0.9336, -0.9135, -0.891],
    ...       [0.0, 0.0523, 0.1045, 0.1564, 0.2079, 0.2588, 0.309, 0.3584, 0.4067, 0.454]]
    >>>img_diagonal = 5
    >>>ro_calc = (point @ sin_cos + img_diagonal).astype(np.int32)
    >>>ro_calc
        array([[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5],
               [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],
               [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
               [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
               [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
    >>>accum = np.zeros((6, 10))
    >>>accum += index * np.apply_along_axis(np.bincount, axis=0, arr=ro_calc, minlength=accum.shape[0])
    >>>accum
        array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
               [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
               [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
               [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1.],
               [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 2., 2., 2.],
               [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 2.]])

    """
    points = np.argwhere(processed_image == mark)
    ro_calc = (points @ sin_cos + img_diagonal).astype(np.int32)

    accum += index * np.apply_along_axis(np.bincount, axis=0, arr=ro_calc, minlength=accum.shape[0])
```

Comment: У вас бОльшая часть кода функции попала в комментарии. Так задумано? Поправьте код, сейчас не очень понятно, что должно быть. И какие-то данные покажите как сгенерировать, на которых проверить.

Comment: А так то я бы попробовал `Numba` применить для начала.